# EagleCAD Device Dimension layer

Tags: eaglecad, dimensions

I am creating an Arduino compatible with minimal parts (ie chip, caps crystal) and since it was available from Adafruit's EagleCad library decided to use the Arduinor3-noioref component for the pad layout.  When I went to build the board I was surprised to see that instead of just having the pads in the right place for a shield it also had a "dimension" layer and drill holes. I am now trying to understand what that means for me when it comes to the actual board dimension since the component already has what I could consider board dimensions.  Should I take the board dimensions and just line them up with the component dimensions as close as I can?   Would appreciate it if someone in the know could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I went to build the board I was surprised to see that instead of just having the pads in the right place for a shield it also had a "dimension" layer and drill holes.

Its uncommon to include dimension in the part definition but practical in some cases. When the gerber output for PCB production is generated, it doesn't matter where the dimension information comes from.

> I am now trying to understand what that means for me when it comes to the actual board dimension since the component already has what I could consider board dimensions.

You don't need to (and shouldn't) draw another dimension outline in this case. As I already pointed out, when looking at the raw gerber data it won't make any difference if it was placed as part of the component or separately.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the last time I deleted the generate board area and tried to move the shield dimension eagle yelled at me.  This time it didn't maybe I did something wrong the last time that I don't recall now.  Thanks for the help